# Pyramid application using OpenID

Tags: python, openid, pyramid, wsgi

I would like to use OpenID authentication in a small Pyramid web application. Most projects I found are old and/or their status is unclear. My requirements are quite simple:

I want to protect access to some parts of the app. It's no high security stuff, but I don't want to care about user registration, password encryption, ... No fancy integration of multiple authentication sources, ...

Is there a simple, known working solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [velruse](http://pythonhosted.org/velruse/) in the past to have OpenID authentication on Pyramid, and it worked well.

However, if what you want is just a way to authenticate users without dealing with the boring parts, [Mozilla Persona](https://login.persona.org/) might be what you are looking for. One of the advantages over OpenID is that any email address can be used to log in; it's not limited to OpenID addresses. There an easy-to use [library to use it with persona](https://pyramid_persona.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (disclaimer : I wrote it).

Comment: I was just looking at your repository and will give Persona a try. ;-)